# How to proceed with this Coq Proof?

Tags: logic, coq, theorem-proving

I'm having a problem with my Coq proof and was hoping for some help and guidance. I have part of my definition below:

```
Inductive Architecture : Set := 
| Create_Architecture (Arch_Name: string)(MyComponents: list Component)
  (MyConnections: list Connector)

with

...

with 

Connector : Set :=
| Create_Connector (Con_Name:string) (client: Component)(server:Component)
```

I wish to say that "A component term must be either a client or server of a connection; but not both." I have come up with the following as a representation of the above in the Coq (based on my definition above):

```
(forall con:Connector, forall c:Component, In con (MyConnections x) -> 
(c = (client con) /\ c <> (server con)) \/ (c <> (client con) /\ c = (server con)))
```

However, I'm not sure if that is correct (is it?), as when I get to the proof, I get stuck at the point

```
5 subgoals
con : Connector
c : Component
H0 : Connection1 = con
______________________________________(1/5)
c = HotelRes
```

The type of `HotelRes` is indeed Component (in this case, `HotelRes` is the client of the connection), however, since this is not in the set of assumptions, I can't use something like the exact or auto tactics.

How could I proceed with such a proof?

Answer (score 2):

From the (part of the) definition that you have shown there is clearly nothing preventing a Component to be both a client and a server in a connector, so I don't understand how you want to prove it?

My guess is that your definition does not properly capture what you want to model, but it's impossible to say more without seeing neither (full definition nor the idea behind it).

Comment: There isnt anything preventing it, no. But I wish to prove that it is indeed the case. I have defined a few connections and wish to prove that this condition holds for them.

Comment: Ok, but if a component can be both a client and a server part of a connector then clearly you can find counter-examples to your lemma, so you cannot hope to prove it. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ahh, so you want to prove it for one particular architecture? I missed that in your original description. That should be easy. But the goal you are showing indeed seems impossible to prove. So there must be something wrong before. I can try to help but it would be easier if you provide a working script (possibly simplified).